# Laravel ajax login empty fields

Tags: ajax, laravel, authentication

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and its Auth scafolding.

I'm trying to make the default login form, to work with Ajax (without reloading page).

I'm using reqwest.js for ajax requests.

Here's my ajax code:

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/lib/reqwest.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var thisForm = document.querySelector('#authLogin');
thisForm.addEventListener('submit', function(f){
  f.preventDefault();
  reqwest({
    url: thisForm.getAttribute('action'),
    method: thisForm.getAttribute('method'),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.getElementById('csrf_meta').getAttribute('content')
    },
    data: '_token='+thisForm.elements._token.value+'&email=myemail@live.com&password=12345',
    success:function (response){

    }
  });
});
</script>
```

It uses `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php` login() function to handle the login requests: https://i.gyazo.com/bfe6790934f711f4c1d35f6670c20caa.png

Here's the problem:

1) when I use the default normal login form `/login` (without ajax), `$request->all()` in the above class returns  all the form fields that were submitted (great, this is perfect)

2) but when I submit the same form `/login` via an Ajax POST request, `$request->all()` returns empty array: https://i.gyazo.com/44e2fc6f438bba27a2baab9f7d3b38d6.png

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong here? I'm going insane and have no idea what may going wrong. I have searched everywhere for a solution, still nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm stupid, I figured out the reason it returns empty array.

In my ajax request I had `contentType: 'application/json',` but my form data was not in JSON format but string params format.